# Material-ui Textfield auto-scroll up the window on first redux-form/FOCUS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autoscroll, onfocus, redux-form

I made a form using [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) with [Textfield](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field) from [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) to send an email. Everything is working well except a single thing : When I click on a TextField for the FIRST time, the window scroll uptop. Sometime, the focus stay on the TextField. Afterward it's working fine

Here's an example of what's happening [Example](https://gyazo.com/e790ea8339d8541d4ed4fde7e1ef7754)

My form:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import styles from './EmailForm.css';
import theme from '../../../theme/theme';
import { mediaQueries } from '../../../decorators';

export const fields = ['name', 'email', 'subject', 'message'];

const validate = values => {
   ...
};

@mediaQueries
@withStyles(styles)
@reduxForm({
    form: 'EmailForm',
    fields,
    validate
})
export default class EmailForm extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        submitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        mediaQueries: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    state = {
        mobile: false,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.mediaQueries('(max-width: 399px)', () => {
            this.setState({ mobile: true });
        });
        this.props.mediaQueries('(min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 919px)', () => {
            this.setState({ mobile: true });
        });
        this.props.mediaQueries('(min-width: 920px)', () => {
            this.setState({ mobile: false });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { fields: { name, email, subject, message }, handleSubmit, submitting } = this.props;
        const emailMarginLeft = this.state.mobile ? 0 : '8px';

        // SOME STYLE HERE

        return (
            <form
                className={styles.form}
                onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                <div className={styles.nameAndEmail}>
                    <TextField style={nameFieldStyle}
                        floatingLabelText="Votre Nom"
                        floatingLabelStyle={labelStyle}
                        floatingLabelFocusStyle={labelFocusStyle}
                        errorText={(name.touched && name.error) ? name.error : ''}
                        errorStyle={errorStyle}
                        id="nameField"
                        {...name} />
                    <TextField style={emailTextField}
                        floatingLabelText="Votre courriel"
                        floatingLabelStyle={labelStyle}
                        floatingLabelFocusStyle={labelFocusStyle}
                        errorText={(email.touched && email.error) ? email.error : ''}
                        errorStyle={errorStyle}
                        id="emailField"
                        {...email} />
                </div>
                <div className={styles.subjectAndMessage}>
                    <TextField style={textField}
                        floatingLabelText="Sujet"
                        floatingLabelStyle={labelStyle}
                        floatingLabelFocusStyle={labelFocusStyle}
                        errorText={(subject.touched && subject.error) ? subject.error : ''}
                        errorStyle={errorStyle}
                        id="sujet"
                        {...subject} />
                    <TextField style={messageTextField}
                        floatingLabelText="Message"
                        floatingLabelStyle={labelStyle}
                        floatingLabelFocusStyle={labelFocusStyle}
                        errorText={(message.touched && message.error) ? message.error : ''}
                        errorStyle={errorStyle}
                        multiLine
                        rows={5}
                        id="message"
                        {...message} />
                </div>
                <RaisedButton
                    style={buttonStyle}
                    key="submitButton"
                    type="submit"
                    label="Envoyer"
                    primary
                    disabled={submitting} />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

The component using the form :

```
@withStyles(styles)
export default class ContactUs extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(data) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.contactUs}>
                <h2>Formulaire</h2>
                <EmailForm
                    ref="EmailForm"
                    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                    submitting />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The theme imported contain the color used for material-ui style.
I have also found that onFocus and onBlur props of the TextFields doesn't work. I tried to simply log text and it doesn't work.

What makes it even weirder is that it isnt the first time I'm using this emailForm. I used it on another site and it was working perfectly fine.

Anyone has an idea of why it's happening?

Comment: Hey, what version of Material UI and redux-form you are using?

Comment: material-ui: ^0.15.1
redux-form: ^5.3.1

Comment: Ok, same as I'm using here. Have you tried to isolate the problem by removing fields and simplifying the form?

Comment: Found it. It was because I had scroll-behavior imported... Don't need  it so  i deleted it and everything is fine